# Error CS0234 in VS 2015 with build+intelliSense selected

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

When I open my mvc project (mvc5) with razor helper file in app_code folder, the compile was successful but in error list I have the error  below:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'global_asax' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The error only appear when the option "Build + IntelliSense" was selected, if I select "Build Only" the error won't show.

Can someone explain why this error occurs and how to eliminate this error? is this a bug in VS2015 since this issue does not occur in vs2013? should I be concerned with this error?

bty the error points to the code below

```
public RazorHelper() {
}

protected static ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
    get {
        return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
    }
}
```